# How to sign a executable program using SignTool?

Tags: python, powershell, sockets, chat, signtool

I wrote a simple chat in Python. The IP and server port are specified in the code. I packaged the entire client part into .exe. Everything works fine for me. But when I transfer to other PCs, the program is immediately blocked, which is logical because I didn’t sign it. I wrote the code in Visual Studio Code, therefore, as I understand it, there is no menu for signing the program.

So I used the command line.

```
PS C:\Users\D-UC> & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\signtool.exe" sign /a /fd SHA256 "C:\Users\D-UC\Documents\POP-CHAT\POP-CHAT.exe"
```

And I got this result
`SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.`

Please tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: Do you have a code signing certificate installed on the machine you're trying to sign from? Keep in mind that the code signing certificate either has to come from a certificate authority (CA) that's trusted by default, or that computers that need to trust your certificate also need to trust the CA that was used to create the certificate.

Comment: The signtool.exe will check all certificates any get latest with SHA256.  You may have an expired certificate or the certificate may not be loaded.  I would run PS as an Admin by right clicking PS shortcut and selecting Run As Admin and see if code runs.